# Pass arbitrary props in a component with some required props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I made a React component like this

```
const GlobalDialogView = ({
  PassedComponent,
  open,
  size,
  bodyDivider,
  bodyClasses,
  headerTitle,
  dismiss,
  ...rest
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Dialog open={open} handler={() => {}} size={size ? size : "md"}>
        {headerTitle && <DialogHeader>{headerTitle}</DialogHeader>}
        <DialogBody
          className={`${bodyClasses ? bodyClasses : ""}`}
          divider={bodyDivider ? bodyDivider : false}
        >
          <PassedComponent {...rest} />
        </DialogBody>
      </Dialog>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

I declared the additional Proptypes like this:

```
type Props = {
  PassedComponent: React.ComponentType;
  open: boolean;
  headerTitle?: string;
  bodyDivider?: boolean;
  bodyClasses?: string;
  size?: "xs" | "sm" | "md" | "lg" | "xl" | "xxl";
  dismiss?: DismissType
};
```

Now I want to make this `GlobalDialogView` a reusable component, and for the `...rest` I want to pass arbitrary props:

```
<GlobalDialogView open={open} PassedComponent={AnotherComponet} value={"another componet value"} anotherRandomProp="" />;

const AnotherComponet = ({ value, anotherRandomProp }) => {
  return <Fragment></Fragment>;
};
```

Is it possible to make in TypeScript? How can I do that?
I know I can achieve this by putting `any` on `GlobalDialogView` prop type, but I really need some props to be required there. Is there any TypeScript solution?

Comment: It seems like they're not _arbitrary_, so much it's a generic component whose additional props should be whatever `AnotherComponet` needs.

Comment: how to declare those additional props in typescript in `GlobalDialogView ` component?

Comment: please review my answer and mark it as Correct if it helped you, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this (although I recommend a different approach) by having prop type for passed component

```js
type TPassedComponentProps = {
  bar: string;
  foo: boolean;
} & Record<string, any>; // you can use unknown instead of any but you'll have to do extra casting

type Props = {
  PassedComponent: React.ComponentType<TPassedComponentProps>;
  open: boolean;
  headerTitle?: string;
  bodyDivider?: boolean;
  bodyClasses?: string;
  size?: "xs" | "sm" | "md" | "lg" | "xl" | "xxl";
  dismiss?: boolean;
}
```

Now any component passed as `PassedComponent` will have to have the mandatory props (because of `React.ComponentType<TPassedComponentProps>`);

My preferred way of doing it is to pass the props for `PassedComponent` in a different prop like this:

```js
type Props = {
  PassedComponent: React.ComponentType<TPassedComponentProps>;
  passedComponentProps: TPassedComponentProps;
  open: boolean;
  headerTitle?: string;
  bodyDivider?: boolean;
  bodyClasses?: string;
  size?: "xs" | "sm" | "md" | "lg" | "xl" | "xxl";
  dismiss?: boolean;
}
```

and use it like this

```
const GlobalDialogView = ({
  PassedComponent,
  passedComponentProps,
  open,
  size,
  bodyDivider,
  bodyClasses,
  headerTitle,
  dismiss,
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Dialog open={open} handler={() => {}} size={size ? size : "md"}>
        {headerTitle && <DialogHeader>{headerTitle}</DialogHeader>}
        <DialogBody
          className={`${bodyClasses ? bodyClasses : ""}`}
          divider={bodyDivider ? bodyDivider : false}
        >
          <PassedComponent {...passedComponentProps} />
        </DialogBody>
      </Dialog>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

this way you have better control over what gets passed to `PassedComponent` and you can have different value for the same prop if you need to, for example your `GlobalDialogView` can have `open={true}` and `PassedComponent` have `open={false}`